# How can I speed up this loop

Tags: excel, vba, autofilter, listobject, excel-tables

I have a Vba code that is very slow on 25 sheets, I am wondering if this code can be speeded up in any way

```
Sub Obracun_place_OLP_NEAKTIVNO()
    '
    ' Obracun_place_NOVI Makronaredba
    '
    Call Refresh_neto_TM
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        Sheets("PODUZEĆE_PLAĆA").Select
        Range("B7:H7").Select
        Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
        Selection.ClearContents
        Sheets("Neto plaća").Select
        ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Tablica_Upit_iz_MS_Access_Database_14").Range. _
            AutoFilter Field:=204, Criteria1:=Range("A2")
        ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Tablica_Upit_iz_MS_Access_Database_14").Range. _
            AutoFilter Field:=207, Criteria1:="<>"
        Range("GV11:GZ11").Select
        Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
        Selection.Copy
        Sheets("PODUZEĆE_PLAĆA").Select
        Range("B6:F6").Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        Sheets("Neto plaća").Select
        Range("E11:F11").Select
        Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
        Selection.Copy
        Sheets("PODUZEĆE_PLAĆA").Select
        Range("G6:H6").Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        Columns("B:H").Select
        Columns("B:H").EntireColumn.AutoFit
        Range("A2").Select
        Sheets("Neto plaća").Select
        ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Tablica_Upit_iz_MS_Access_Database_14").Range. _
            AutoFilter Field:=207
        ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Tablica_Upit_iz_MS_Access_Database_14").Range. _
            AutoFilter Field:=204
        Sheets("PODUZEĆE_PLAĆA").Select
        Range("B5").Select
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=COUNTIF((R[2]C:R[100]C),R[-4]C[-1])"
        Range("E5").Select
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(R[2]C:R[100]C)"
        Range("E5").Select
        Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("E5:F5"), Type:=xlFillDefault
        Range("E5:F5").Select
        Range("B6:H6").Select
        Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
        ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("PODUZEĆE_PLAĆA").Sort.SortFields.Clear
        ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("PODUZEĆE_PLAĆA").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range( _
            "C7:C129"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
            xlSortNormal
        With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("PODUZEĆE_PLAĆA").Sort
            .SetRange Range("B6:H129")
            .Header = xlYes
            .MatchCase = False
            .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
            .SortMethod = xlPinYin
            .Apply
        End With
        Range("B7:H7").Select
        Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
        With Selection.Interior
            .Pattern = xlNone
            .TintAndShade = 0
            .PatternTintAndShade = 0
        End With
        Sheets("PLAĆA_SPISAK").Select
        ActiveSheet.Range("$C$10:$G$60").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<>"
        Sheets("PODUZEĆE_PLAĆA").Select
        Range("B5").Select
        Sheets("2001").Select
    Range("A1").Select
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Macro-recorder code is slow because it mimics a user clicking and selecting cells. You must rewrite it using `Range` variables instead and remove all `Range.Select` instructions. Most copy/paste operations don't need to involve the clipboard, either;  if you only need the values you can take them from one range to another as a single operation.

Comment: You might benefit from reading [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10714251/4996248).

Comment: Can you show me at least one copy of it on this example of mine?

Comment: `Sheets("Neto plaća").Select
        Range("E11:F11").Select
        Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
        Selection.Copy`  It has 3-times a `Select`, which is not needed when you read the linked question/answer.

Comment: Sheets("Neto plaća").Range ("E11:F11")  like this

Comment: Yes but then that's all implicitly late-bound and will be very prone to error 438. Declare and use variables instead, and have `Option Explicit` at the top of the module. `Dim sourceSheet As Worksheet` / `Set sourceSheet = Worksheets("Neto plaća")` / `Dim someRange As Range` / `Set someRange = sourceSheet.Range("E11:F11")` / then you'll have intellisense and parameter completion when you want to do anything with `someRange`.

Answer (score 2):

### Getting Rid of Active and Select (Translating Macro-Recorder Code)

- Not tested.
- There is still much room for improvement but it should illustrate what it could look like.
- It compiles but that doesn't mean it's gonna work. Give it a try and share some feedback.

**Issues**

- If there is no match in the table, the code will fail.
- If the data isn't 'nice' and has empty rows, the `xlDown` lines will fail.
- Maybe it would be preferable to write the formulas in *A1 style*.

**The Code**

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Obracun_place_OLP_NEAKTIVNO()
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    'Refresh_neto_TM '?
    
    ' Reference the workbook ('wb').
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    ' Reference the source worksheet ('sws').
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Worksheets("Neto plaća")
    Dim stbl As ListObject
    Set stbl = sws.ListObjects("Tablica_Upit_iz_MS_Access_Database_14")
    
    ' Reference the destination worksheet ('dws').
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Worksheets("PODUZEĆE_PLAĆA")
    
    ' Clear the (old) destination data range (headers are in row 6).
    With dws.Range("B7:H7")
        .Range(.Cells, .End(xlDown)).ClearContents
    End With
    
    ' Filter the source table.
    With stbl
        ' Clear possible existing filters.
        If .ShowAutoFilter Then
            If .AutoFilter.FilterMode Then .AutoFilter.ShowAllData
        Else
            .ShowAutoFilter = True
        End If
        ' Filter.
        .Range.AutoFilter Field:=204, Criteria1:=CStr(sws.Range("A2").Value)
        .Range.AutoFilter Field:=207, Criteria1:="<>"
    End With
    
    ' Copy the data from the source to the destination worksheet.
    With sws
        With .Range("GV11:GZ11")
            .Range(.Cells, .End(xlDown)).Copy dws.Range("B6:F6")
        End With
        With .Range("E11:F11")
            .Range(.Cells, .End(xlDown)).Copy dws.Range("G6:H6")
        End With
        sws.Columns("B:H").EntireColumn.AutoFit
        'Application.Goto sws.Range("A2") ' reset to initial selection
    End With
    
    ' Clear the table filters.
    stbl.AutoFilter.ShowAllData
    
    With dws
        
        ' Reference the (new) destination range ('drg').
        Dim drg As Range
        With dws.Range("B6:H6")
            Set drg = .Range(.Cells, .End(xlDown))
        End With
        
        ' Write formulas.
        Dim lfRow As Long: lfRow = drg.Rows.Count ' last formula row
        .Range("B5").FormulaR1C1 _
            = "=COUNTIF((R[2]C:R[" & lfRow & "]C),R[-4]C[-1])"
        .Range("E5:F5").FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(R[2]C:R[" & lfRow & "]C)"
        
        ' Sort by the 2nd column ('C').
        With .Sort
            .SortFields.Clear
            .SortFields.Add _
                Key:=drg.Columns(2), _
                SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, _
                Order:=xlAscending, _
                DataOption:=xlSortNormal
            .SetRange drg
            .Header = xlYes
            .MatchCase = False
            .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
            .SortMethod = xlPinYin
            .Apply
        End With
    
        ' Apply formatting.
        With drg.Resize(drg.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1) ' 'drg' without headers
            With .Interior
                .Pattern = xlNone
                .TintAndShade = 0
                .PatternTintAndShade = 0
            End With
        End With
    
        'Application.Goto .Range("B5") ' reset to initial selection
    
    End With
    
    ' These are irrelevant, the second one probably not necessary!?
    wb.Worksheets("PLAĆA_SPISAK").Range("C10:G60").AutoFilter 1, "<>"
    'Application.Goto wb.Worksheets("2001").Range("A1")
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: FROM this code of yours, I tried to figure out how to include other code, but I keep getting an error with .Range.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=(sws.Range("A2").Value)